# GSON causing StackOverFlow Error when running toJSON

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, stack-overflow

**Before I begin with the question, I know there are lots of similar questions to this but I have no control of the objects I turn into JSON therefore I can't simply exclude fields that reference the same object.**

I found that explaining the structure of my applications help people understand my question more, so here I go!

I have 2 applications, a Logic application (where all the heavy operations take place) and a Instrumented application (an application which is injected into an old game and has to be kept light).

The 2 applications communicate via RMI (Remote Method Invocation).

The Instrumented Application sends Objects that are fetched from the old game using the Reflection API to the Logic Application (via RMI as that's how the 2 communicate).

Most of the objects are Un-serializable (Do not implement Serializable, and can't be serialized except by using BCL libraries which I don't want to do as it's bad practice to force-serialize objects as they may cause problems(security) serialized).

As mentioned in the above paragraph, due to them being un-serializable I can't just turn them into byte arrays and send so I've went through and used GSON which doesn't require the objects to implement Serializable.

When I first tried out serializing the objects, it worked except a couple of objects printed out Stack overflow errors when trying to serialize them (toJSON).

Why I think the error occurred:
The object has a superclass..
The object contains references of itself (Fields)

I can't show the object itself as it's in a game and its obfuscated, but I can show my wrapper to it which shows the fields and their types.

The Object Itself (The one causing Stack Overflow errors when toJSON is executed upon it) :

```
public class NPC extends Model {

    //The Class itself contains 1 field which is "Composite"

    public NPC(Object object) {
        super(object);
    }

    public NPCComposite getComposite() {
        return new NPCComposite(getFieldValue("Npc.composite", object));
    }
}
```

The Object above contains only 1 Field and it's "Composite", here's the wrapper for NPCComposite:

```
public class NPCComposite extends Wrapper {

    //Contains 3 Fields: String[], String, int (Nothing out of the ordinary)
    
    public NPCComposite(Object object) {
        super(object);
    }

    public String[] getActions() {
        return (String[]) getFieldValue("NpcComposite.actions", object);
    }

    public int getID() {
        return (int) getFieldValue("NpcComposite.id", object);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return (String) getFieldValue("NpcComposite.name", object);
    }
}
```

If you have noticed, the Object itself (NPC) has a superclass, this is the superclass's wrapper:
I have added a comment next to field getters that have unapparent return types.

```
public class Model extends Render {

    public Model(Object object) {
        super(object);
    }

    public int getFineX() {
        return (int) getFieldValue("Model.localX", object);
    }

    public int getFineY() {
        return (int) getFieldValue("localY", object);
    }

    public int getAnimation() {
        return (int) getFieldValue("animation", object);
    }

    public int getAnimationDelay() {
        return (int) getFieldValue("animationDelay", object);
    }

    public int getCombatTime() {
        return (int) getFieldValue("combatTime", object);
    }

    public int getStandAnimation() {
        return (int) getFieldValue("standAnimation", object);
    }

    public int getFrameOne() {
        return (int) getFieldValue("frameOne", object);
    }

    public int getFrameTwo() {
        return (int) getFieldValue("Model.frameTwo", object);
    }

    public Object getHealthBars() { //Returns a Health Bar Object
        return getFieldValue("Model.healthBars", object);
    }

    public Object getHitCycles() { //Returns an Integer 1D Array
        return getFieldValue("Model.hitCycles", object);
    }

    public Object getHitDamages() { //Returns an Integer 1D Array
        return getFieldValue("Model.hitDamages", object);
    }

    public Object getHitTypes() { //Returns an Integer 1D Array
        return getFieldValue("Model.hitTypes", object);
    }

    public int getInteracting() {
        return (int) getFieldValue("Model.interacting", object);
    }

    public Object getMessage() { //Returns a String
        return getFieldValue("Model.message", object);
    }

    public int getOrientation() {
        return (int) getFieldValue("Model.orientation", object);
    }

    public int getQueueSize() {
        return (int) getFieldValue("Model.queueSize", object);
    }

    public Object getQueueTraversed() { //Returns a byte 1D array
        return getFieldValue("Model.queueTraversed", object);
    }

    public Object getQueueX() { //Returns a 1D int array
        return getFieldValue("Model.queueX", object);
    }

    public Object getQueueY() { //Returns a 1D int array
        return getFieldValue("Model.queueY", object);
    }

    public int getRuntimeAnimation() {
        return (int) getFieldValue("Model.runtimeAnimation", object);
    }

}
```

Main method:

```
    Gson g = new Gson();
    String res = g.toJson(NPCObject);
```

Error:

```
java.rmi.ServerError: Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:303)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:279)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:163)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:235)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:180)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getGSONValue(Unknown Source)
    at main.Instance.test(Instance.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.StringWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.string(JsonWriter.java:590)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:401)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.value(JsonWriter.java:526)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$11.write(TypeAdapters.java:311)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$11.write(TypeAdapters.java:296)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245)
    at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:1027)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245)
```

**My question is:** Is there anyway to solve this error? or is there any other JSON library that can serialize such objects? any answer is appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Well, this is a classical issue that can be fixed by introducing the [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) pattern: one designs very simple (almost zero domain logic, but not necessarily simple for the structure) classes that can handle domain objects to support particular de/serialization libraries.

Comment: Simply speaking, de/serialization domain objects is very and very common and sometimes causes awful design choices and issues (in my practice I came across a real project that had domain objects that were all domain entities and DTOs therefore annotated with dozen annotations from various libraries and frameworks "just to write less" (sic): Hibernate, Jackson, XStream, custom annotations).

Comment: So here comes the solution #1: simply design lightweight classes to convert from your domain objects easily and transfer using Gson easily (_domain objects_ -> _DTO objects_ +> _[send]_); on the receiving side simply do the opposite (_[receive]_ +> _DTO objects_ -> _domain objects_). There may require more additional work, but it keeps application layers separate and _maintainable_.

Comment: Of course, except of having more mapping classes, you have to track circular references yourself, but this the former can be implemented with mapper constructors, and the latter would require to design a way to indicate references (say, special fields in DTO classes like `__my_$ref` and `__my_$id` that would also allow to linearize the object graph). Why not having it in the serialization library like Gson? An answer: what if you migrate to another library someday?

Comment: @fluffy What do you mean by DTO? It's a generic term meaning Data transfer object.. do you mean that I create an object and take the values of the domain object/NPC and insert them into the object then send? (Like a wrapper) or is it something specific?

Comment: @fluffy I get what you mean so like Domain Object -> Fields -> New Object -> Client. but the thing is the game has a lot of objects from different types.. this means I have to make a wrapper for every object. also making DTOs will put a strain on the server / memory-wise. and I want to keep it light (the instrumented app is the server)

Comment: Yes, that's the main purpose of DTO: decouple whatever domain you have and its _representation_ for the representation layer.

Comment: Gson is not a very appropriate tool to work with circular references, and its design is kind of not flexible to built something like that on top what Gson has, so you have to make a decision: either use a more appropriate tool or a Gson extension; or use DTO to track circular references back and forth (again, there are semi-automatic mappers than can half-help, but there's nothing free); or find any other way by implementing a custom `TypeAdapterFactory` (I guess it's not that easy, but definitely doable).

Comment: @fluffy understood thanks, what about XStream I hear that it handles circular references?

Comment: Possibly, no idea, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully solved this by using XStream and adding the class path of the objects to it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way around it except using BCEL libraries and changing circular fields to transient or making the class Serializable and its contents..